# Album arts are not updated in windows media library

Tags: mp3, windows-media-player, id3, album-art

I keep my audio files tagged in windows media library.

I have media information using a ID3 tag editor. Album Arts(thumbnails) are not updated in the media library. But correct album arts are displayed while playing the media.

How I can I force windows media player to update the album art info?

I think the album art thumbnails are cached by wmp.

Comment: Which version of WMP on which version of Windows? You mention ID3, so I assume that these are MP3 files? How exactly are you changing the album art of the files?

Comment: As i'm out of my desk, i can't give u the wmp version. But it's the default version with windows8, so i guess wmp13. I use a tag editor(mp3 tag) for tagging.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that WMP is closed, then go to the folder containing the audio files and delete the hidden `Folder.jpg` and `AlbumArt*.jpg` files. These files contain the album art that was automatically downloaded by WMP, so it might be a good idea to back them up first.

If you can't see these files, make sure that Explorer is set to show hidden files and folders, and to show protected operating system files.

Then start WMP again. The songs for which you manually deleted the old, cached album art should get updated with their new, embedded art.

Comment: FYI: Its not just one or two album. There are a number of albums (1000+). Deleting from each won't be an easy task.

Comment: You can use the search functionality in Explorer to find all `*.jpg` files in your Music library. Then these files can be deleted in one go.

Comment: I have a better way to do that using a shell script. FYI: Album arts are updated in the thumbnails(explorer) but not in wmp.

Comment: For the album art to get updated, you may also need to clear WMP's art cache, by deleting all hidden JPG files in the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Media Player\Art Cache\LocalMLS` folder while WMP is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script I made. (I'm not an expert but works) This will go through all folders and sub-folders, delete two images and create two fake images. Windows Media Player won't be able to show those, so it'll show the AlbumArt embedded in mp3 file.
Clt + C to cancel at any time.

Just save this code in a text file (you can use Notepad) and save it as .bat file instead of .txt and just run it in the main Music folder. (Without admin)

```
@pause
for /r %%s in (Folder.jpg) do (
    @echo %%s
    attrib -h -s %%s
    del /f /q %%s
    type nul > %%s
    attrib +h +s %%s
    cacls %%s /P everyone:n
)
    for /r %%t in (AlbumArtSmall.jpg) do (
    @echo %%t
    attrib -h -s %%t
    del /f /q %%t
    type nul > %%t
    attrib +h +s %%t
    cacls %%t /P everyone:n
)
@pause
```